# application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: not called when there is a MainWindow.xib

Tags: ios, hyperlink, deep-linking, openurl

I've sifted through the various other posts regarding openURL not being called and none of them apply to my case, so here's another.

I am trying to implement deep linking. I am able to open the app from a link, so my url scheme works. However, the openURL method never gets called.

I'm on iOS 8.

If I remove the MainWindow.xib I get a black screen (haven't sorted out the details of programming it in), but the openURL method gets called when it should.

My company isn't exactly the project's owner, so ideally there would be a way to make the openURL work with MainWindow.xib or show some document stating that this is not supported.

code:
in my applicationdelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    NSLog(@"open %@",url);
    return YES;
}
```

and in info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
    <string>com.something.appish</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>schemename</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <string>Viewer</string>
</dict>
</array>
```

The links i use are schemename://anything and com.something.appish://anything

These open up my app or bring it to the forefront, but do not result in an openURL call.

previous posts on the subject include:

1. openURL should be defined in the application delegate, not view controller.
2. try handleOpenURL (for earlier iOS versions).
3. url scheme not defined correctly.
4. app not installed case.
5. trying to open particular files.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. You provide an issue and you described it well. Now all that missing is the code you implemented handling these actions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank you. I've added the code to the post.

Comment: hmm yeah, all seems to be well with your code and set up. Have you tested on a real device? Try opening it with `schemename://anything` and then log `NSLog(@"%@", [url host]`

Comment: yes, this is on a real device.

Comment: well if you haven't tried to do a Clean then I'm out of ideas

Comment: I did clean (and deleted derived data) :(. Thanks for having a look soulshined.

Comment: @soulshined I've updated my post and would be grateful if you took another look. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So turns out, a static library (for which i had source access) swizzled the openURL.

thanks!